# Adding text (titles) to video - ffmpeg vs ..?

Tags: video, text, ffmpeg

is there a better (faster processing-wise & having more options) way to add titles (text) to video then ffmpeg?

Surely I can use "drawtext" in ffmpeg, but what would be the best way to go if I wanted to add an outline to font etc..?

Comment: What do you mean by, "an outline to font"?

Comment: Also, have you considered using subtitles instead (specifically softsubs). Otherwise you have to re-encode if you want to use `drawtext`.

Comment: I mean this kind of outline: http://forum.high-logic.com/postedimages/OutlineR.png

Comment: Will the text change during the duration of the video, or is it going to be static for the whole video?

Comment: It will change (also move across the screen / fall down etc..). Also the text itself will be different from frame to frame..

Comment: `drawtext` can not created the outlined text as for as I know, and I do not believe it can move the text. Timing and text changing over time could be an issue too. `overlay` could add PNG with transparencies, but again the moving and changing would take some work.

Comment: is there a better tool for this then ffmpeg?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12516/discussion-between-lordneckbeard-and-stpn)